# Not able to fetch recent record by date

Tags: mysql

I have executed the below query to get latest record but it shows record of previous month instead of latest record.

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM merchnat_tbl_sells_rc t1
  WHERE t1.S_Date = (SELECT MAX(t2.S_Date)
                       FROM merchnat_tbl_sells_rc t2
                       WHERE t1.MID = 'MNJ')
```

I want output as :

[image: Output I Want]

But it gives me output as :

[image: Output I Have]

Comment: s.date does not look like a mysql date (yyyy-mm-dd) so what datatype is it?

Comment: it's in dd-mm-yyyy and it's varchar

Comment: Then you need to convert it to a date before trying to get max see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Is there any way to convert from varchar to date datatype without data loss, as if i change directly all value of s_date will become 0000-00-00

Comment: Not with you - can you provide sample data as text in the question?

Comment: S_Date having value 26-12-2018 in VarChar get converted into 0000-00-00 on changing it to date datatype, this is happening with all S_Date values

Comment: Who said anything about changing the data type. You only needed to convert the varchar using str_to date in the query. Did you read the link?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simplified example of using a date stored as varchar.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int auto_increment primary key,dt varchar(10),merchant int);

insert into t (dt,merchant) values
('01-01-2019',1),('27-12-2018',1);

select t.* ,str_to_date(dt,'%d-%m-%Y') dtConvertd,
        (select max(str_to_date(dt,'%d-%m-%Y')) from t t1 where t1.merchant = t.merchant) maxdt
from t 
where str_to_date(t.dt,'%d-%m-%Y') = (select max(str_to_date(dt,'%d-%m-%Y')) from t t1 where t1.merchant = t.merchant)

+----+------------+----------+------------+------------+
| id | dt         | merchant | dtConvertd | maxdt      |
+----+------------+----------+------------+------------+
|  1 | 01-01-2019 |        1 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-01 |
+----+------------+----------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort the result. In your query, you should use `order by`.
Remove `max`

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM merchnat_tbl_sells_rc t1
  WHERE t1.S_Date = (SELECT TOP 1 t2.S_Date
                       FROM merchnat_tbl_sells_rc t2
                       WHERE t1.MID = 'MNJ'
                     ORDER BY t1.S_Date DESC)
```

Comment: Getting syntax error near 1 t2.S_Date
                       FROM merchnat_tbl_sells_rc t2
             ' at line 3

Comment: @jned29 The mysql equivalent of the sqlserver TOP is limit.